# Send Nested JSON With POST Request iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, post, swift3, xcode8

I want to send JSON to Server with POST request but i did not understand how i do this. I select friends from table view and show these friends in my Collection view. And the selected peoples shows in collection views and their email are sent in JSON to Create group. Here is my code written in Swift.

```
@IBAction func createGroupButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let groupName = groupNameTextField.text

    let adminEmail = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userEmail")


    if groupName == "" {

    alertMessage(msg: "Enter Group name")

    }

    else if base64String == nil {

        alertMessage(msg: "Select Group Image")

    }

    else if emailArray.isEmpty {

        alertMessage(msg: "Select atleast one person")

    }


    else {


    if isNetAvailable {

        var emailData: String?

        print("email data \(emailArray)")

        for i in emailArray {


         emailData = "\"email\":\"\(i)\""

        }

    let postData = "\"name\":\"\(groupName!)\",\"adminemail\":\"\(adminEmail!)\",\"image\":\"\(base64String!)\",\"emailArray\":\"\(emailData!)\""


    let postDat = "jsondata={\(postData)}"

    print("Post Data \(postDat)")


    let urlString = create_group

    let url = URL(string: urlString)


    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = postDat.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {

        print("Something wrong with creating Group")

        }

        if data == nil {

            print("Nil Data")

        }

        if response == nil {
            print("Nil Response")

        }

        if response != nil {
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            print("Response String is \(responseString)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    }

    else {
        alertMessage(msg: "Internet Not Available")
     }

    }        
}
```

Here is my API

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] !="POST"){ exit; }
require_once 'dbcon.php';
if (!empty($_POST['jsondata']))
{
$configjson = $_POST['jsondata'];

$config = json_decode($configjson, true);

$groupname = $config['name'];
$adminemail = $config['adminemail'];
$image = $config['image'];

$queryemailcheck = "SELECT * FROM groups_name WHERE admin =   '$adminemail' AND groupname = '$groupname'";
$selectquery = mysqli_query($connect, $queryemailcheck);
$totalemails= mysqli_num_rows($selectquery);
if($totalemails>0)
{
echo "Already exist";
}
else {
$queryinsert= "INSERT INTO groups_name(admin , groupname , pic ) VALUES('$adminemail' ,'$groupname' , '$image')";

if(mysqli_query($connect, $queryinsert)){
    echo "Successfully Saved";
}else{
    echo "Error: " ;
}
$members = $config['emailArray'];
foreach($members as $row ){
$email = $row['email'];

$queryinsert2= "INSERT INTO group_members(groupname , member , status    ) VALUES('$groupname' ,'$email' , '0')";

if(mysqli_query($connect, $queryinsert2)){
    echo "Successfully Saved";
}else{
    echo "Error: " ;
}
}

}

}

else echo "post data is empty";
?>
```

Comment: check your json format, that seems not correct, if you are passing json object, you would use  NSJSONSerialization class to get data then set it in http body

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alamofire library for handling your webservices. like

```
Alamofire.request(logoutUrl, method: .post, parameters: dict, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:["Authorization":"Bearer \(accessToken)", "Accept":"application/json", "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"]).responseJSON { (response) in

            let json:JSON = JSON(response.result.value)

            let status =  json["status"].stringValue
            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
```

Comment: I did not use Alamofire. I am using URL Session and i want to do this task this way i doing.

Answer (score 0):

Create network handler class where you can hit webservices from all of your app.

```
func makeHttpPostRequest(uri:String, postBody:Dictionary<String, Any>  ,Completion:@escaping (_ response: AnyObject, _ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    let networkCheck = self.getNetworkStatus()
    if networkCheck == false {
        Completion("NO internet connection." as AnyObject,false)
        return
    }//end network check block
    var urlRequest = self.makeHttpRequestWithUrl(url: uri)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    //check and set authorization header
    if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: AppConstant.KAppAuthenticationToken) != nil) {
        let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: AppConstant.KAppAuthenticationToken) as! String
        urlRequest.setValue("Token token="+authToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }
    //let postData = [self.addDefultParameters(detailDict: postBody)]
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postBody)
    urlRequest.httpBody = jsonData

    //create connection
    self.httpConnectionWithRequest(request: urlRequest, Completion: Completion)
}

func makeHttpRequestWithUrl(url: String) -> URLRequest {
    let urlString = AppConstant.baseUrl+url
    let networkUrlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: urlString)!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 50)
    return networkUrlRequest
}

func httpConnectionWithRequest(request: URLRequest, Completion:@escaping (_ response: AnyObject, _ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error is: " + String.init(format: "%@", error?.localizedDescription as! CVarArg))
            Completion(error!.localizedDescription as String as AnyObject, false)
            return
        }
        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            Completion("didn't get response data" as String as AnyObject, false)
            return
        }

        let responseString =  String.init(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8)
        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides

        if let resp = response as? HTTPURLResponse{

            if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: AppConstant.KAppAuthenticationToken) != nil) {
                if resp.statusCode == 401{
                    //auth token expired

                    self.makeRequestWithNewToken(request: request, Completion: Completion)
                }
            }
            //check if response is Array or dictionary
            var jsonArray:[Any]?
            var jsonDict:[String:Any]?


            // response is in array
            do{
                jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])as? [Any]
            }catch{
                print("response doesn't contain array")
            }
            //response is in dictionary
            do{
                jsonDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])as? [String:Any]
            }catch{
                print("response doesn't contain dict")
            }
            //=====
          //  if resp.statusCode == 200{

                if jsonArray != nil{
                    Completion(jsonArray! as AnyObject, true)
                    return
                }

                if jsonDict != nil{
                    Completion(jsonDict! as AnyObject, true)
                    return
                }

                Completion("didn't get response data" as String as AnyObject, false)
                return
        }

    }
    task.resume()
        }
```

And through the completion handler you will get the fetched data.